# JQuery appended data is not available at POST request

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, dom

I am trying to append data from a list of data from database to a text-area. Data is being appended but it is not available at post request.

Can you please guide me why I am not getting data at my controller?

user interface

[image]

```
 <textarea id="summernote" name="description" rows="25">
         <ul>
            <li id="description"></li>
         </ul>
  </textarea>


 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.task_id').on("click", function(e) {          
          e.preventDefault();   
            debugger;           
            var task = $(this).text();            
            var task_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
            $('#'+ task_id).css("cursor", "not-allowed");
            $('#'+ task_id).css("color", "grey");            
            $('#'+ task_id).off('click');
            
            var task = $.trim(task);
            var task_li = "<li>"+task+"</li>";
            var description = $('#description').append(task_li);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Don't post your code as an image... Code is text, please copy and paste it into your question.

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis. Let me edit my post now.

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan for guide me. I have studied help center and how to ask page. I think I have learned from there.

Comment: Where is your `post` request? Or ajax call?

Comment: Not ajax call. I am trying to send form data normally.

Comment: Sorry, I am not seeing any `form` here.

Comment: I wonder if Summer Note is like CKEditor; with that plugin, if you dynamically update the content via Javascript, you need to call a command to sync that back to the `<textarea>` element. If you don't, and try to submit the form, the `$request->input('description')` is empty. Do some searching for that, see what comes up :)

Comment: Yes I have fixed it by creating a hidden field called description and assigned data to the value. It is working now. Thanks a lot @TimLewis

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Perfectionist for your help.

Comment: Excellent! Feel free to add that as an answer below. Then, when the system allows it, you can self-accept it to properly close this question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by creating a hidden field called description and assigned data to the value. It is working now. Thanks a lot @TimLewis